# Groovy + Oracle sql, how to create a table and pass variables at same time

Tags: sql, oracle, groovy, insert

Good evening to you all.

I'm using groovy java and I'm trying to create a table inside the oracle database.

I know that I can do that in two times.
first place, create the table and then insert the variables that are coming from my Array output.

This is my Array:

```
[[Paulo, Alves, Ducati, 33, London, Valentino Rossi]]
```

This is my table:

```
// sql scriptcreates a table
        def createTableScript = """
            CREATE TABLE MOTOGP(
                 FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
                 LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50),
                 AGE NUMBER,
                 ADDRESS VARCHAR(50),
                 ALIAS VARCHAR(50)
            )"""
        // execute the create table script
        sql.execute(createTableScript);
```

I want to pass my variables or Arry objects to the table at the same time as the creation. It is possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No, it isn't, at least in the way that you suggest. It would be possible using `CREATE TABLE AS {SELECT STATEMENT}`, but it doesn't seem like a clean way to do it.

Comment: As an aside, trying to store "age" is a serious design flaw.  "age" is constantly increasing, and so constantly needs updating.  Instead of storing the age of someone (or some_thing_) store the DATE from which "age" is calculated.  For a person's "age", you should store date of birth.  And when storing a date, declare the data type to be DATE.  Then, you can always calculate the _correct_ date whenever you query the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Groovy, but - based on what you described - perhaps it is `CTAS` (Create Table As Select) you're looking for. In Oracle, it looks like this:

```
SQL> create table motogp as
  2    select cast('Paulo'            as varchar2(20)) first_name,
  3           cast('Alves'            as varchar2(20)) last_name,
  4           33 age,
  5           cast('London'           as varchar2(20)) address,
  6           cast('Valentino Rossi'  as varchar2(20)) alias
  7    from dual;

Table created.

SQL>
```

The result is then:

```
SQL> desc motogp
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 FIRST_NAME                             VARCHAR2(20)
 LAST_NAME                              VARCHAR2(20)
 AGE                                    NUMBER
 ADDRESS                                VARCHAR2(20)
 ALIAS                                  VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> select * From motogp;

FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                   AGE ADDRESS              ALIAS
-------------------- -------------------- ---------- -------------------- --------------------
Paulo                Alves                        33 London               Valentino Rossi

SQL>
```

Note `CAST`s I used; without it, table's columns would have length equal to current column values and different datatype (`CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR2`) and that's probably not what you'd want to have. For example:

```
SQL> create table motogp as
  2    select 'Paulo' first_name
  3    from dual;

Table created.

SQL> desc motogp;
 Name                          Null?    Type
 ----------------------------- -------- --------------------
 FIRST_NAME                             CHAR(5)

SQL>
```

---

Now, how to do that in Groovy, no idea; I hope that this is good enough to get you started.